# how to apply bitand on multiple ranges in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 3 columns, where each column contains some random numbers. I am going to find out how many numbers in the first column and second column have a non-zero output from [`BITAND`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bitand-function-8a2be3d7-91c3-4b48-9517-64548008563a).

For example, assuming two columns A, B

```
A    B
1    0
2    64
4    8
8    7
16
```

- 0 and 64 in B have no single bit "1" in common with any number in A.
- Number 8 in B have common bit 1 with the 8 in A.
- Number 7 in B have common bit 1 with number 1, 2, 4 in A.

Therefore, there are total of 4 pairs of numbers with non-zero `BITAND` result.

I find that Excel's `BITAND` does not support operation on a range of cells and therefore I am using a very inefficient method to do the work. Assuming the first column has 100 numbers and the second column has 55 numbers.

1. I first fix one number in the second column and have each number in the first column `BITAND` with that number, which will generate a new column of 100 numbers.
2. Repeat the same procedure with the 1st column and the next number in the second column until all numbers in the second number looped.
3. That will generate a total of 55 additional columns each have 100 results of `BITAND`.
4. I then count the total number of non-zero entries.

I wonder if there is any better method instead of macro that will help to reduce the work since I may have more than 200 numbers per column in the future.

PS a sample Excel with my solution could be downloaded at [enter link description here](https://gofile.io/d/1rJNSZ)

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired output? Also post what you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using formulas, you could try a simple grid where `b` is transposed over the columns. Each grid cell has formula `=BITAND(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are references to `D4:D8` and `E3:H3`.

In cells `E2` put `=COUNTIF(E4:E8,">0")` which you can drag across to the right.

Then, in cell `E1` put `=SUM(E2:H2)` to get the desired output of 4

[image]

You can accommodate new entries to `a` and `b` and extend the matrix without breaking the existing result (as `BITAND(0,0) = 0`):

[image]

I've used 14 extra rows in `a` and 7 extra rows for `b`, but this can be any number you like - the output number will still end up in cell `E1`. To semi-automate the transpose

- in row 3 you can use `=INDEX($B$2:$B$12,COLUMN()-4)` where `4` is constant in reference to column `D`
- in column `D` the formula is simply `=A2` and drag down

[image]

If you know the upper limit on the number of rows you expect in the future, you can set it up for that and let it grow over time simply by adding new values to `a` and `b`.